# How do I prove that a curve has unique endpoints?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $C\subset X$.

Let $\alpha,\beta : [0,1]\rightarrow X$ be an injective paths such that $\alpha([0,1])=\beta([0,1])=C$.

How do I prove that $\{\alpha(0),\alpha(1)\}=\{\beta(0),\beta(1)\}$?

Since $[0,1]$ is connected, this must be true, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ is Hausdorff and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are injective, they are both homeomorphisms onto $C$. That means $\gamma=\beta^{-1}\alpha$ is an automorphism of $I=[0,1]$. The points $0$ and $1$ are characterized by being the only *non-cut points* in $I$, which are points $x\in I$ such that $I\setminus\{x\}$ is still connected. Can you show that a homeomorphism sends non-cut points to non-cut points? After doing that, can you finish the proof of your claim?